# Android VideoView create excessive info/warning messages

Tags: java, android, android-mediaplayer, android-logcat, android-videoview

I have a VideoView in my Android project and whenever it is playing I get an unreasonable amount of LogCat messages. The video is playing fine, and I see no user facing errors, but I get an info/warning message every second or so.

`W/MediaPlayer﹕ info/warning (3, 0)
W/MediaPlayer﹕ info/warning (36866, 100)
W/MediaPlayer﹕ info/warning (702, 0)
W/MediaPlayer﹕ info/warning (36865, 0)
W/MediaPlayer﹕ info/warning (36865, 0)
W/MediaPlayer﹕ info/warning (36865, 0)
W/MediaPlayer﹕ info/warning (36865, 0)
W/MediaPlayer﹕ info/warning (36865, 0)
W/MediaPlayer﹕ info/warning (36865, 0)
W/MediaPlayer﹕ info/warning (36865, 0)
W/MediaPlayer﹕ info/warning (36865, 0)
W/MediaPlayer﹕ info/warning (36865, 0)
W/MediaPlayer﹕ info/warning (36865, 0)
W/MediaPlayer﹕ info/warning (36865, 0)
W/MediaPlayer﹕ info/warning (36865, 0)
...`

I couldn't find any reference to error code 36865. Is this normal behaviour? If so, is there any way I can suppress this message for a more usable LogCat?

Answer (score 1):

Possible that you are hitting MEDIA_INFO_VIDEO_TRACK_LAGGING

http://developer.android.com/reference/android/media/MediaPlayer.html#MEDIA_INFO_VIDEO_TRACK_LAGGING

The number is very much implementation dependent (which play is playing it under the hood). But it would be you are seeing microsec video is late by.

You can use setOnInfoListener to get call back and explore them further.

Comment: Shouldn't I be getting an `info/warning (700, 0)` in that case as per the reference you suggested?

Thanks for the setOnInfoListener idea; I'll check that out shortly.

Comment: My OnInfoListener only gave me 'what'=36865 and 'extra'=0. So not much help there.